# Android - finish activity and exit app

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I have an application which consists 3 activities - lets call them A, B & C.
From activity A You can get to activity B, from B to C and from C to A (By pressing the back button).

On activity A I have an exit button (I know it`s not recomandded on android, but a lot of users are asking for it, so I decided to add it).

Anyway the problem is that: activity B has a timer, when the timer is finished it starts an intent that starts activiy C and calls finish() on activity B.

When the user then press back on activity C he gets to activty A - and then when he presses the exit button (this button only preforms finish()), it pops up activity B again. How can I prevent it from happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand how you end up at A when going back from C. Shouldn't it go back to B (logically, I mean. I know you *want* it to go to A)? In fact, that seems to kind of be what's happening. B is getting relaunched, but A appears on top of it, so that when you finish A, B (which was under it) is now shown.

It sounds like you don't want B to be part of the history stack, so maybe when you launch B, you should launch it with the [no history flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY).

Comment: The B activity is a game`s level, so when the game is over (activity C) I dont want the player to get back to the game itself, but rather to the main activity (activity A).

Answer (score 2):

Idea: set a `isFinished` field in your `Application` to true and call `finish()`. All activities check if `isFinished` in their `onResume()` and if true they `finish()`.

Comment: If you describe the manner of failure then I can try to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You activity b is not finished thats what i can figure out it is still in running state so when all other actitivties are finished it shows up please chekc if it is finished or not